# Is it possible to match a POST element to another name in a Model

Tags: playframework-2.0

Using PlayFramework 2.0.1, I have a model :

```
class MyModel extends Model {
    @Constraints.Required
    public String someProperty;
}

class MyController extends Controller {
    public static Result action() {
        Form<MyModel> form = form(MyModel.class).bindFromRequest();

        if (form.hasErrors()) {
            // Return errors
        }
        else {
            // Process
        }
    }
}
```

Suppose I post with `mysite.com/action?some-property=value`. How can I match `some-property` from the request, to `someProperty` to the model? Is it possible?

Because so far, it `hasErrors()` fire `true` since `someProperty` appears missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't add constraints to the model, instead validate and bind it manualy:

```java
// ...
MyModel some = MyModel.find.byId(id);
String someFromReq = form().bindFromRequest().get("some-property");

if (someFromReq == null || someFromReq.equals("")){
    return badRequest();
}

some.someProperty
some.update();
// ...
```

Comment: But if I add Constraints on my Model's element, hasErrors fire true :/ (I updated my question regarding it, it was missing this point, sorry :/)

Comment: Good, but what if I have 10 fields in my model, I will have to process all them ?

Comment: But well, I think the best answer your first line : "Don't add constraint to the model, bind it manually". Maybe an annotation for the model would be great, something like `@BindFrom("some-property")`

Comment: I don't know the BindFrom annotation, btw maybe it's just easier to use `route`: `POST  /action/some-property/:someProperty    controllers.Application.action(someProperty:String)` and use link like `domain.tld/action/some-property/value` ? of course in such case `someProperty` will be passed as a action's argument and whole form will be available with bindFromRequest