# How to update / save only changed fields

Tags: playframework-2.0, ebean

How can I update only a particular set of fields to the database with Play? Currently I have a `User` model that contains a specific field, let call it: `isAdministrator`:

```
private boolean isAdministrator;
```

And I have the accessor methods:

```
/**
 * @return the isAdministrator
 */
public boolean isAdministrator() {
    return isAdministrator;
}

/**
 * @param isAdministrator
 *            the isAdministrator to set
 */
public void setAdministrator(boolean isAdministrator) {
    this.isAdministrator = isAdministrator;
}
```

But when I change the username, via a form where `isAdministrator` is NOT included, Play resets my User objects and sets the value `0` for this user?

So, how can I update only the changed fields?

Comment: Maybe you'll find some conclusion in this discuss: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/play-framework/jYNlO5vDn7A/tlm_uYe1FIoJ

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't directly answer to your question, but instead of having a boolean indicating that your User is an admin or not, I would create an `Admin` class which inherits from the User.

```
public class Admin extends User {
....
}
```

It's the "[S](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle)" of [SOLID](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solid_%28object-oriented_design%29) ;-)

**EDIT:**

In the controller, you can load the old value from the database before updating with the form values:

```
...
User userFromDB = User.findById(anId);
User userFromForm = userForm.get();

// set previous value
userFromForm.setArchived(userFromDB.getArchived());

User.update(userFromForm);
...
```

Comment: Yes, I'm currently doing that :-), but still I have a field called, `isArchived`. So still need this :-)

Comment: The `isArchived` field is at the `User` level ? Why not adding it to your form ? Or you can also load the old value from the db before updating with the form values (see my edit).

Comment: I do not want to add it to the form, because this is the user self, that is changing his profile. It would be silly to mark himself as archived :-). Looks like the solution is a seperate POJO form, but why is Ebean doing this? Why not update only changed fields?

Comment: You don't have to add it in the HTML form.

Comment: I don't understand that: you say add it to the for, but not in the HTML? Only solutions looks like, you have suggested, getting the object from DB before saving.

Comment: Sorry, I was talking about your form object (not HTML one); see http://www.playframework.org/documentation/2.0.2/JavaForms

Answer (score 2):

In addition to **nico's** answer I only can add, that you don't need to use `Form` class in every case. Sometimes it's enough to just get data from request and update your object manually which useful especially with ajax calls when you have detailed level of intermediate saving (see example of use of the [DynamicForm](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11618359/1066240) it can be even shorter and also [you can validate it yourself](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11359506/1066240):

```
public static Result updateName(Integer id){
    User user = User.find.byId(id);
    user.name = form().bindFromRequest().get("name");
    user.update(id);
    return ok();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can specify the fields you want to update. Say you want to update the *name* then you will do like this:

```
Ebean.update(user, new HashSet<String>(Arrays.asList("name")));
```